# Ubuntu 10.10 - PC shutdown before boot shortly after BIOS loads

Tags: ubuntu, boot

Since installing Ubuntu 10.10 from Karmic I've started getting problems with starting up the PC. I've done a complete wipe (Boot and Nuke) of the hard drive and reinstalled Ubuntu 10.10 but the problem still occurs. There is no dual boot on the PC, just Ubuntu.

**Here is the problem:**

Each morning, when I turn the PC on from being off overnight, the PC starts up and loads the BIOS. I get the following message

```
Verifying DMI Pool Data... K8 NPT Data Change...Update New Data to DMI!.......
```

Then *poof* the computer shuts off.

However, after switching the computer back on around 6 or 7 times after it's turned itself off, it will eventually boot up without any problem.  Also, once up and running for a while, I can shutdown and restart the PC first time, without any issues.

I have also noticed a problem with the USB mouse being recognised and once I finally get the computer booted up, I need to unplug and then plug the mouse back in to get it working.

I've opened the PC up and checked the connections (cables, cards and memory) and it all seems fine.  The main issue with troubleshooting this problem is I cannot test any suggestions or fixes until the next morning because once the computer is up and running it will remain so! I do not leave the computer on overnight to save energy.

So.. **Is this a hardware / boot software issue?** This is a very odd problem and I have googled to no avail. Any suggestions?

Comment: How old is the motherboard? The 6 or 7 reboots seems to me like a problem with capacitors on the motherboard. As they get old, thy need more time to charge.

Comment: It's from 2006 / 2007. But what you've said sort of ties in with my last post about leaving the PC on at the boot selection screen :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like failing capacitors to me. Open the chassis and look at the motherboard - do you see capacitors like this:

[image]

Power circuitry failing is one of the usual ways for motherboard to "expire". Symptoms include "cold" boot failing more often than "warm" boot. Be careful, bad capacitors can also burn your CPU over time, because capacitors are used to "level off" spikes, and capacitors failing suspects CPU to less equalized power.

Answer (score 0):

DMI strings are usually hard burned into the BIOS.  From an OS guy's perspective - not my problem.  Have you tried flashing the BIOS to clean?

Comment: I'm unsure how to do this. I have, however, tried resetting the BIOS settings to the 'default' and then 'optimum' but this didn't help. It's almost like the computer is 'cold' and needs to warm up before the boot sequence works, which is why I checked the connections.

Comment: thinking you need to flash the bios from the DMI complaint....motherboard name/type?

Comment: something makes me want to say the battery on your motherboard might not be good (my memory is fuzzy). you might try replacing that to see if it helps.

Comment: AKING1012 - -core
       description: Motherboard
       product: www.abit.com.tw
       vendor: NF-M2SV
       physical id: 0
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Phoenix Technologies, LTD
          physical id: 0
          version: 2006/12/19 (04/04/2007)
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 448KiB
          capabilities: isa pci pnp apm upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect socketedrom edd int13floppy360 int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer int10video acpi usb ls120boot zipboot

Comment: was it a clean board or installed by an OEM(dell etc)

Comment: It was a clean board.

Comment: Xantec - the battery theory is interesting, as it may explain why the PC doesn't work straight away from a 'cold' start.

Comment: yep, battery is where i go next...last is the trying to force a fake oem of windows and you got an openbox mobo without knowing it

Comment: Next question on the back of the battery suggestion: What type of battery do I need based on the m/board info above and where can I get one from?

Comment: walmart has them in jewelry electronics and hardware...or radio shack  they type i don't know, but bringing the dead one with you and visual inspection should do it

Comment: Got myself a pack of 8 batteries for £1.00 (no walmart here!) :) Replacing the battery didn't fry the mother board or cause problems so I shall wait until the morning to see if it has worked......

Comment: Sorry for the delay in my update. It didn't work... But it doesn't take as many attempts to get the PC up and running and now it goes past the BIOS, boots up Ubuntu and then shuts off. Didn't get that far before... Any ideas?

Comment: to try and diagnose the boot shutdown edit your kernel line in grub and disable quit...see if it produces any meaningful output

Comment: Hello again. I don't think it's anything to do with the boot sequence. I power on then the pc shuts off as usual, as above. Power up a second time and Ubuntu loads up the boot select / safe mode boot selection screen (realising the problem with the first boot). Previously, I would select the usual boot several times before the PC started up correctly. However, and here's the part which makes me think the PC hasn't warmed up.... If I leave the PC on at the boot selection screen for 5-10 mins, go back and select the usual boot option and it works perfectly fine, first (technically second) time.

Comment: Have you added anything recently? If so, have you thought about an underpowered PSU?  Rebooting several times makes me think of blown capacitors or HDs not spooling up fast enough.

Comment: @Xantec it's probably not the battery - I've had them die on older computers before- they still boot fine but show a BIOS warning sometimes.  Even if you don't have a BIOS battery it won't loose anything until you unplug the computer from the wall or turn off the switch on the power supply

Answer (score 0):

It could be a bad power supply - they go bad eventually.  If you have spare computer try swapping the power supplies to see if that fixes the problem.

The hard-drive spinning up during boot could push it over the edge and cause enough of a voltage drop to turn off the system.

I replaced everything in a computer once trying to fix random lock-ups (reusing the case and power supply of course...) - then it died entirely on the new motherboard and I realized it was the power supply all along.

Also make sure the outlet you are plugging it into is properly grounded - if the motherboard isn't grounded properly there can be a voltage built up that trips the internal circuit breaker in the motherboard. (Running a computer without a power supply screwed into the case can cause some computers to turn off after a few seconds)